# System can delete a file, but my program can't?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I have a file that can't be deleted by using File.Delete() - "Permission denied" or DeleteFile(). With the standard way it can be deleted without any problem. Using Unlocker, it showed that no handle is attached.

EDIT:
The file was opened in another application. I don't know why Unlocker didn't detect it.

Comment: Check the value being passed into `File.Delete()` to make sure it is your actual path. Note that each \ in file name should show up as \\ in a string.

Comment: Just check points

1. Permission /credentials your code running in
2. File really present when ur code running
3. No other process accessing file.

Comment: What system do you use? Occasionaly Vista and Win7 denies the permission to delete unless you run the program in administrator mode or you set the proper permissions/credentials in your program

Answer (score 1):

Look at the Parent Directory and the File's property's security tab. Verify what permissions are granted to them. This should let you know what your problem is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it says, the application running has no access to that file.
If your application created that file, check if you're calling the delete with the same credentials. If your application did not create this file, it's possible it's in a location that you don't have access to.

Comment: The file is located in temp and the file is created by another application.

Comment: then this can be an owner conflict.